# How modify css transform with js

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, transformation, translate

I need to add translate to some of elements, problem is some of them already have rotation.
I trying to modify my transformation matrix, but sometimes it has 6 sometimes 16 elements. Plan is to translateX half of item width.

```
var page = $("<div>");
this.pages.push(page);
page.css({                
            "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
            "-webkit-transition-duration": "0.5s"
        });            
for (var i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
        var matrix = this.pages[i].css("transform");

        if (matrix != "none")
            matrix = matrix.replace(/[^0-9\-.,]/g, '').split(',');
        else
            matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ];
        var index = matrix.length == 16 ? 3  : 2;            
        matrix[index] = -0.5;                
        this.pages[i].css({ "transform": "matrix(" + matrix.join(",") + ")" });
        }
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, there is no css method in JavaScript.  Are you using jQuery?  If so, it doesn't look your element is wrapped in the jQuery method.  Please share more of your code.  We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  A snippet would be perfect so the community can easily help you instead of downvoting.

Comment: Thank for yout advice i added code how pages array is created. Yes im using jquery, but jquery work fine the transform sometimes change but not exacly like i want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your code with just a couple of changes:

- Don't use the `-webkit-` prefix for transform.  Every browser has un-prefixed support for `transform` for a decade or more now.
- In jQuery, you'll already have an iterable collection of elements that are returned to you. No need to try and create a separate array of "pages".
- Prefer the built in jQuery `each()` method to a for loop when you're trying to loop over a jQuery collection.  Just pass it a function that will be run on each object in your collection.  The function will be passed an index and the element as `this`.
- I think it's easier to use slice to get the values from the matrix versus a regular expression.  It's easier to reason about what you're trying to accomplish.

Working snippet is annotated further:

```js
const $pages = $("div"); /* this is already iterable */
$pages.each(addTranslateY); /* using jQuery's each method */

function addTranslateY(i) {
  /* get the current transform values */
  const transformMatrix = $(this).css("transform");
  /* get the width in pixels */
  const width = $(this).width();
  /* create an array from the string matrix values */
  const transformArray =
    transformMatrix === "none"
      ? [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
      : transformMatrix
          .slice(7, -1) /* get just the values in the parens */
          .split(", ") /* split the string into an array */
          .map(Number); /* convert each value into a number */

  /* change the f value of the matrix */
  transformArray[5] += width / 2;

  /* update the element with the new matrix */
  $(this).css("transform", `matrix(${transformArray.join(", ")})`);
}

/*
  transformArray values:
  a represents scale x [0]
  b represents skew x [1]
  c represents skew y [2]
  d represents scale y [3]
  e represents translate x [4]
  f represents translate y [5]
*/
```

```css
div {
  background-color: deeppink;
  height: var(--size, 3rem);
  width: var(--size, 3rem);
  margin: 1rem;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background-color: blue;
}

.skew {
  transform: skew(30deg);
  background-color: orange;
}

.scale {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(100px, -50px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div class="rotate" style="--size: 3rem"></div>
<div class="skew" style="--size: 2rem"></div>
<div class="scale" style="--size: 6rem"></div>
<div class="translate" style="--size: 5rem"></div>
```